# TensorFlow 2: getting multiple tensor values in a single call to TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

In TensorFlow 1 (without eager execution) I could get multiple tensor values in a single call to `Session.run` as follows:

```
# The tensors variable is a list containing multiple tensors
tensor_values = sess.run(tensors)
```

This is useful, since there is some overhead to each call to `Session.run` (calling into the TensorFlow runtime).

In TensorFlow 2 I'd like to achieve the same result, while using `tf.function` to optimise execution. So I can do something like the following:

```
@tf.function
def my_func(tensors):
    return tensors
```

My question is: does this result in a single call to the TensorFlow runtime, in the same way as the TensorFlow 1 code? I've tried inspecting the code that autoflow generates, but it's not obvious from this.

Comment: If all the arguments for ```my_func``` are tf.tensors, then there will be a single graph construction on the first call.

Comment: @iyop45 Thanks for your reply. Yes, the TensorFlow documentation is clear that a single graph is constructed, but I want to know whether all tensor values will be retrieved in a single call to the TensorFlow runtime.